# How do I get response headers for AWS JavaScript SDK calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I have a simple AWS Lambda function which makes an S3.getObject() call as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.logger = console;

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return await getObject({
    Bucket: "<MY-BUCKET>", 
    Key: "<MY-KEY>"
  }).then( (res) => {
    console.log('Retrieved object from S3');
    console.log(res);
    return res.Body.toString('ascii');
  })
};

async function getObject(params){
  return await s3.getObject(params).promise();
}
```

I've enabled logging SDK calls as per [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/logging-sdk-calls.html).

How do I get response headers for the `s3.getObject()` SDK call that was made? I am basically trying to retrieve the S3 request ID and extended request ID.

The in-built logger added via the "AWS.config.logger = console;" line does not seem to log response headers. How else do I get response headers for AWS JavaScript SDK calls?

P.S: Bonus points if you can let me know whether or not I need **two** `await` keywords in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to `httpHeaders` event.

```
var requestObject = s3.getObject(params);

requestObject.on('httpHeaders', (statusCode, headers, response, statusMessage) => {
    // your code here.
});

requestObject.promise()
    .then(response => { ... })
```

Comment: The doc is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#httpHeaders-event